# Help solving the differential equation $y''+y'+y=0$ with initial conditions $y(0)=4,y'(0)=-3$ using Laplace transform.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, laplace-transform

**UPDATED WTH ANSWER:**

Please help me solve the following differential equation using Laplace transform:
$$y''+y'+y=0;y(0)=4,y'(0)=-3$$

My answer so far:
$$\mathcal{L}\{y''\} + \mathcal{L}\{y'\} + \mathcal{L}\{y\}=0$$
We know that $\mathcal{L}\{y'\} = s\mathcal{L}\{y\}-y(o)$ and $\mathcal{L}\{y''\}=s\mathcal{L}\{y'\}-y'(0)$. Upon substituting this to the equation,  it becomes
$$s\mathcal{L}\{y'\}-y'(0)+s\mathcal{L}\{y\}-y(0)+\mathcal{L}\{y\}=0$$
$$s(s\mathcal{L}\{y\}-y(0))-y'(0)+s\mathcal{L}\{y\}-y(0)+\mathcal{L}\{y\}=0$$
$$s^2\mathcal{L}\{y\}-sy(0)-y'(0)+s\mathcal{L}\{y\}-y(0)+\mathcal{L}\{y\}=0$$
Upon substituting the values of initial conditions the equation becomes
$$s^2\mathcal{L}\{y\}-4s+3+s\mathcal{L}\{y\}-4+\mathcal{L}\{y\}=0$$
Solving for $\mathcal{L}\{y\}$:
$$\mathcal{L}\{y\}(s^2+s+1)-4s+3-4=0$$
$$\mathcal{L}\{y\}(s^2+s+1)=4s+1$$
$$\mathcal{L}\{y\}=\frac{4s+1}{s^2+s+1}$$
Modifying the numerator and denominator to obtain the form similar to one of the them in the [Laplace transform table](https://cdn.hashdoc.com/docs/6f4c05851c74744eeb11aa9a53dce822/images/728x/table-of-laplace-transforms-1.png). 
First applying the method of completing the square to the denominator:
$$\frac{4s+1}{s^2+s+1} = \frac{4s+1}{(s^2+s+\frac{1}{4})+(1-\frac{1}{4})}=\frac{4s+1}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}$$
Then modifying the numerator:
$$\frac{4s+1}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}=\frac{4s+2-1}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}=\frac{4(s+\frac{1}{2})-1}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}$$
Divide the fractions:
$$\mathcal{L}\{y\}=\frac{4(s+\frac{1}{2})}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}-\frac{1}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}$$

Taking the inverse of Laplace transform of $\mathcal{L}\{y\}$ and let it be $y$. Then the equation becomes
$$y=4\mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{(s+\frac{1}{2})}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2)}] - \mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{1}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}]$$

The inverse of the first fraction is:
$$4e^{\frac{-1x}{2}}\cos(\frac{\sqrt3x}{2})$$

To match the second fraction to one of the forms from the Laplace Transform table, we need to multiply the numerator and denominator by $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$. Then it becomes: 
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}]$$
Therefore the inverse of the second fraction is:
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt3}e^{\frac{-1x}{2}}\sin(\frac{\sqrt3x}{2})$$
FINAL ANSWER:
$$y=4e^{\frac{-1x}{2}}\cos(\frac{\sqrt3x}{2})+\frac{2}{\sqrt3}e^{\frac{-1x}{2}}\sin(\frac{\sqrt3x}{2})$$
                      //

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\mathcal{L}(s)=\frac{4\left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right)-1}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}$$

therefore

$$ f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}\left(4\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)\right)$$

In case there remains some mystery concerning how to know to replace the $4s+1$ with $4\left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right)-1$, since after completing the square in the denominator we see that it contains $\left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$ we must then replace the $4s$ with $4\left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right)$. But seeing that this changes the numerator to $4s+2$ we subtract the $1$ to keep the numerator the same after the adjustment.

Comment: If you factor out 4, then the numerator of the first part becomes 4(s-1/8)

Comment: @socrates Is not $4\left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right)-1=4s+1$?

Comment: right........
...

Comment: how did you get 2sqrt(3)/3 in front of the second part?

Comment: Still have not checked my answer, however. Doing that now.

Comment: I'm not getting $y^\prime(0)=-3$ so working the problem from scratch. Also, $\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}\right)=\sin(ax)$ therefore, $\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s^2+a^2}\right)=\frac{1}[a}\sin(x)$.

Comment: THE FINAL BOOK ANSWER: $$ f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}\left(4\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)-\frac{2}{√{3}}\sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)\right)$$

Comment: So my answer is correct, then. I will have to re-check. I thought it did not give the correct result for $y^\prime(0)=-3$.

Comment: Just not noticed my Latex error in the earlier comment: it should have been $\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s^2+a^2}\right)=\frac{1}{a}\sin(ax)$

Comment: I double-checked. My answer and the book's equivalent answer do give $y^\prime(0)=-3$. You realize of course that $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

Comment: BUT $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}\} = \sin(ax)$$, not $$\frac{1}{2}\sin(ax)$$

Comment: There is something you are not understanding here and I am not quite sure what it is. But the fact that $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}\} = \sin(ax)$ directly implies that $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{1}{s^2+a^2}\} =\frac{1}{a} \sin(ax)$. I am not sure why you are not seeing this. Remember that Laplace transforms and their inverses are *linear*.